# Setting up host file to redirect foo.com to localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, macos, port, hosts

I'm trying to test out some Facebook features on my rails application and I would like to use a host file to redirect my `foo.com` to `localhost:3000` when developing.

Here's what I've added to my `private/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1:3000 foo.com
```

Then I flushed my DNS cache:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Yet I still can't access my local rails application using `foo.com`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't set port at hosts file. Port would be setup by rails `rails server -p 3000`

Comment: Port is defaulted to 3000 as usual; I'd rather not tweak that port number (*even though I know I can*). Is there not a way to use port numbers in host files?

Comment: The hosts file is for host name resolution only. You cannot put port numbers in there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still trying this - just add the host entry normally (127.0.0.1 foo.com) and put the host suffix on the URL when you request it.

For example. If you're serving a local site at localhost:3000 and you want to use foo.com to view it, do this:

`127.0.0.1 foo.com` in your hosts file

And then browse to `foo.com:3000` to see your site.